# Inserting an image and forcing it between paragraphs

Tags: graphics, texmaker, include

I am inserting a Figure named Figure1 inside a document in TexMaker using the code below:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline
\ \hspace{10cm}\ \\ \\ \includegraphics[width=5in]{Figure1}\\ \\ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Shows that the number of patients}         \label{f:pic}
\end{figure}
```

However, this image is floating in the text that is before it. How can I force it to be displayed after a particular paragraph and before another paragraph?

Comment: Just remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` the _only_ purpose of that environment is to tell latex it can float the figure to the top of a page.

Comment: Don't use `figure`. simple as that.